# Is this .h correct?

Tags: c

It's strange I have this error:

```
/tmp/ccq0e479.o:main.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to
`ft_putchar' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**main.c :**

```
#include "biblio.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

        ft_putchar(argv[1]);
        return 0;

}
```

**ft_putchar.c :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblio.h"

    void ft_putchar (char* str){
            int i = 0;
            while (str[i] != '\0'){
                    write(1,str[i], 1);
                    i++;
            }
            write(1,'\0', 1);

    }
```

**biblio.h**

```
#ifndef biblio_ft
#define biblio_ft

void ft_putchar(char*);

#endif
```

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: Perhaps the guard `#ifndef biblio_ft` is causing it. It is unnecessary, since you may declare a function prototype as often as you wish, provided they are all the same.

Comment: gcc main.c
i just put
void ft_putchar(char*);
in my .h so ?

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. Is it possible that there is an older version of `main.c` on the compiler's search path, and that version is missing the `#include "biblio.h"` statement?

Comment: how ? i only have this main.c in this directory

Comment: you need to compile both files: main.c and `ft_putchar.c`  then link both files.  One, simplistic, method would be: `gcc -o main main.c ft_putchar.c -I.`    Where it is expected that `biblio.h` is in the same directory as main.c and ft_putchar.c,  However, the file name: `biblio.h` is a very poor choice, suggest: `ft_putchar.h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiling only `main.c` is not enough, you need to compile both files:

```
gcc main.c ft_putchar.c -o myprog
```

or

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c ft_putchar.c
gcc main.o ft_putchar.o -o myprog
```

More info: [Gcc tutorial](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html)

Comment: wtf ?? even if i use a .h ??

Comment: Yes, biblio.h doesn't tell the compiler where to find the code, it only tells: somewhere there is a function named x and this is the prototype